# Typescript create JSON Object Using Interface

Tags: json, typescript

I need to build a custom JSON object for store in PostgreSQL in json field and i use typescript for do this.

In my testing case i have this code:

```
interface Product {
  id: number,
  quantity: number,
}

let prod: Product = {} as any;
interface Products extends Array<Product>{}
let productItems : Products = [];
let productItems2 : Products = [];


let obj = {};
let container = [];

prod.id = 1;
prod.quantity = 10;
console.log("prod1: ", prod);
productItems.push(prod);

prod.id = 2;
prod.quantity = 100;
console.log("prod2: ", prod);
productItems.push(prod);

prod.id =3;
prod.quantity = 34;
console.log("prod3: ", prod);
productItems.push(prod);

obj = { "products1" : productItems}
container.push(obj);

prod.id = 10;
prod.quantity = 10;
console.log("prod2.1: ", prod);
productItems2.push(prod);

prod.id = 20;
prod.quantity = 100;
productItems2.push(prod);
console.log("prod2.2: ", prod);

prod.id =30;
prod.quantity = 34;
console.log("prod2.3: ", prod);
productItems2.push(prod);

obj = { "products2" : productItems2}
container.push(obj);

obj = { "products1" : productItems, "products2": productItems2}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

For some reason when show in console the content for var **productItems**, always display the last item **prod.id = 30 and prod.quantity = 34**.

The array not stored the data for every new product but in console i can see the correct values for every new item.

My required is get an object equal to **obj** with correct values as follow:

```
{
    "products1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 10
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "quantity": 100
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "quantity": 34
    }],
    "products2": [{
        "id": 10,
        "quantity": 10
    }, {
        "id": 20,
        "quantity": 100
    }, {
        "id": 30,
        "quantity": 34
    }]
}
```

If i print the var **container** display a JSON object into [] like array.

What i do wrong?

Here i have my code play 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3nfapq?file=index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're repeatedly mutating the same object rather than making a new object for every item you want to add to the array.

The issue centers on the difference between *variables* and *values*. To see what I mean, let's walk through a part of your code. We start with

```
let prod = {};
```

which declares the variable `prod` and assigns it the value of an initially-empty object in some memory location -- let's say location 1.

Then we hit:

```
prod.id = 1;
prod.quantity = 10;
```

This modifies the object `prod` refers to -- the object at location 1 -- so that it now has id 1 and quantity 10. The next line,

```
productItems.push(prod);
```

pushes the object at location 1 onto `productItems`. So far so god. But next, we have:

```
prod.id = 2;
prod.quantity = 100;
productItems.push(prod);
```

This again changes the object at location 1 to have `id` 2 and `quantity` 100, and then again pushes that object onto `productItems`. So at this point, the object at location 1 is `{id: 2, quantity: 100}` and `productItems` contains two references to it.

To fix this, you need to avoid reusing the same object. You can still use the same *variable* `prod` if you want, but you need it to refer to a different *object* every time you make a new one to put in the array. So for instance, if you wrote:

```
let prod = {} as any;
prod.id = 1;
prod.quantity = 10;
console.log("prod1: ", prod);
productItems.push(prod);

prod = {} as any;
prod.id = 2;
prod.quantity = 100;
console.log("prod2: ", prod);
productItems.push(prod);

prod = {} as any;
prod.id =3;
prod.quantity = 34;
console.log("prod3: ", prod);
productItems.push(prod);
```

then things work as you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it is a concept that I had forgotten, excellent detail in the explanation.